# Password protecting site

Tags: php, javascript

How would I password protect my site? 
I have been throwing around ideas, so far my site is stuck with something similar to this:

```
<script>   
function password() {
var password = prompt("Enter password:");
if (password.toString().toLowerCase() == "pass") {
    location.href = "siteURL";
    return true;
}
else {   
    alert ("Incorrect code");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

However this is not hard to get around.

I was looking for something so that even by going onto the main site, they would be redirected to a password page. If they entered correctly they could return to current page, if not then they would be unable to enter. 
I already have the "password page" sorted. I am just wondering if there is a way to redirect to there and back. Also, would such a thing require cookies to see whether the user has already correctly imputed the password?

If anyone could direct me to useful information on this, it would be much appreciated.

I've added both PHP and Javascript in the tags as I am unsure if this is server side scripting or not.

Comment: ?? Do you mean password protecting a page? you can use `.htpasswd`

Comment: You're looking for a full authentication and/or authorization system? Or a single, general password to something like ... the preview version of a site?

Comment: that could be a possibility. but since i already have the password input page sorted i was looking for a way like i previously described.

Comment: @epascarello sorry, i didn't know whether it could be implemented through JavaScript or if i'd need to learn php to create such a thing, and how to go about learning this.

Comment: It is fairly useless to password-protect a page in this way, as the data is stored in plain text, and is therefore accessible via simple "view source." It is far more advisable to use [.htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) than JavaScript to accomplish this

Comment: You can't use JavaScript alone, because it runs entirely client side.

Comment: Using JavaScript to password protect a page is like placing your key under the front door mat.It is safe until someone lifts it and sees the value. So the answer is do not do it. Pleny of basic examples on the net that shows you how to secure a page with php in a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP this can be done using the session_start() and checking if the user has authenticated via a login page. There are many many tutorials on the web.

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html